# XML processing using Apache Flink

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am a newbie to Apache Flink and distributed processing as well. I have already went through Flink quick setup guide and understand the basics of MapFunctions.
But I couldnt find a concrete example for XML processing.
I have read about Hadoops XmlInputFormat, but unable to understand how to use it.

My need is,
I have huge(100MB) xml file of format as below,

```
<Class>
    <student>.....</student>
    <student>.....</student>
    .
    .
    .
    <student>.....</student>
</Class>
```

The flink processor would read the file from HDFS and start processing it(basically iterate through all the student element)

I want to know(in layman's terms), how can I process the xml and creata list of student object.

A simpler layman's explanation would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Apache Mahout's `XmlInputFormat` for Apache Hadoop extracts the text between two tags (in your case probably `<student>` and `</student>`). Flink provides wrappers to use Hadoop InputFormats, e.g., via the `readHadoopFile()` method of `ExecutionEnvironment`.

If you do not want to use the `XmlInputFormat` and if your XML file is nicely formatted, i.e., each student record is in a single line, you can use Flink's regular TextInputFormat which reads the file line by line. A subsequent `FlatMap` function can parse all student lines and filter out all others.